# None of the bridges work

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge

I am having a bit of an issue connecting to Tor network.

I am currently working as a teacher in Turkey. In our schools there is a fiber cable connection provided by the Ministry of Education. However this network is **extremely** restricted.

I tried every single bridge option, but it doesn't work.

I am using Windows 10 x64. There are no proxy servers needed. I am using Tor via the Tor Browser bundle.

Is there anything else I can do or is it hopeless?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is it doing? If you have some logs, please add them to your question (without the IP addresses of the bridges).

Comment: Have you tried to use pluggable transports (obfs4, meek etc.)?

Comment: Or perhaps have you tried to find more bridges? There are some instructions for achieving that: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#FindingMore